# How to disable days before tomorrow in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable days before tomorrow and set tomorrow as the default  but I cant.my code shows today as the default and disabled days before today.

view:

```
   <input id="date_modified" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
```

jquery:

```
 $('#date_modified').persianDatepicker({
            observer: true,
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            maxDate: new Date(),


        })

                .pDatepicker('setDate');

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
  var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    //Following line of code is to set the default and minDate of datepicker.
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate: tomorrow,defaultDate:tomorrow});
    //Following line of code is to set value of default date on text box.
    $("#datepicker").val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', tomorrow));
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how  to set tomorrow as the default value input?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer to set default date. Use $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({defaultDate:tomorrow}).

Comment: @F.Joodaki, I think you want to set the default value in the textbox. I have edited the Answer again. Hope it solves your purpose.